# Is it possible to import javascript files to a java ScriptEngine

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I am using nashorn java ScriptEngine. I would like to evaluate a script which includes other scripts. I know I can use the load directive directly in the javascript itself, but I would prefer to import or load it directly from the java code instanciating the scriptEngine.
Is there a way to do this ? Something like :

```
void evaluateScript(String scriptName, String dependency) {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine jsEngine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    jsEngine.load(depency); // does not exist.
    jsEngine.eval();
}
```

I see the "load" function does not exist. How could I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I found the answer myself: as mentioned in the comment, it is possible to call several eval with different scripts, same engine, and the engine will keep the evaluated scripts in its context. So here is my code:

```
public void executeScript(String scriptName, String[] dependencies) {
    try {
        FileReader script = new FileReader(scriptName);
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine jsEngine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        if(dependencies != null) {
            for (String dependency : dependencies) {
                FileReader dependencyFile = new FileReader(dependency);
                jsEngine.eval(dependencyFile);
            }
        }

        jsEngine.eval(script);
    }
}
```

I can define functions in my dependencies and use them in the script of name scriptName.

Answer (score 0):

[javax.script.ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) has many "*eval*" methods - there are java.io.Reader accepting *eval* methods like this -> [eval](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval-java.io.Reader-)

You can pass a [java.io.FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) or a [jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.URLReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/URLReader.html) to load script from a file or a URL.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer but it does not fit my question: I want to execute one script theScript, together with other scripts otherScriptList. But I will try eval on different scripts with the same engine and check if the engine keeps the previous ones in his context.

Comment: Yes, same engine keeps "context"!